# How to pass a 3D array from R to C++ using .Call

Tags: c++, r

I could not find how to do this. I have a 3D array in R, and I would like to use it in C++. 
Could anyone help please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's how to define a 2d and 3d array in c++: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/ Hope that at least gets you started

Comment: There are pretty much no multidimensional arrays in C. I have no idea about R, but to pass anything to C you should convert your 3d array to 1d buffer and pass it together with stride information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found the `.Call()` interface which will allow you to pass [R](http://www.r-project.org) objects to C++.  You then have (at least) two choices:

1. Use C and Macros via the R API as describing in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual that comes with R. It works, many people use it and it has passed the test of time.  It is also a little tedious, at least for my tastes.
2. Use C++ via our [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) package and the API it provides on top of the R API.  We do not have too many examples for multi-dimensional arrays, but it can be done.  Internally, these are of course just contiguous vectors with dimension attributes.
3. You could also use [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) to go to [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) which has a proper 'Cube' type, a generalisation to 3d from 2d matrices -- seee the [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) docs.

**Edit:**  Here is a minimal example:

```
R> library(inline)
R> f <- cxxfunction(signature(ms="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
+   Rcpp::NumericVector m(ms);
+   return m.attr("dim");
+ ')
R> A <- array(1:8, c(2,2,2)) # 3-d array
R> f(A)                      # call C++ function defined above to get dim array
[1] 2 2 2
R>
```

It does not do much besides return the dimension vector of the array you passed in. For actual access, you may have to compute the dimension strides by hand -- we simply have not seen much demand for anything beyond matrices.  And the last time I needed this, I just used `arma::cube` from [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) via [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo).